# A scalable solution for sharing objects between threads in web.py (+ flup/fcgi)

Tags: python, threadpool, web.py, fastcgi, flup

I need to share an object between threads in *web.py*. I'm running a web service that performs a calculation & returns a value. The calculation is done using an object that takes up quite a lot of memory, so I don't want it to be created for each request.

I have a solution that works fine, but doesn't seem to scale:

```
import web
urls = ('/', 'index')

class index:
  def GET(self):
    ...
    result = web.myObject.DoCalculation()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = web.application(urls, globals())
  web.MyObject = LoadObjectFromFile
  app.run()
```

*web.py* automatically opens 10 threads, but this number is fixed, and it's very limiting. Can I change that?

The *web.py* [install guide](http://webpy.org/install) recommends using *flup* + a server like *LightTPD*, or *Apache*. Can this be done while retaining the shared object feature that I need? Can anyone tell me how?

I installed *flup* and added "**fcgi**" as a command line parameter when starting the server. This gave me the desired behaviour in terms of threads (unlimited number), but of course didn't perform any task. An *fcgi* sever needs to be defined, I think. Can this be fixed without running *LightTPD*, or *Apache*?

Comment: What property does not scale? Is it slow when testing with lots of requests or do you mean the limit of those 10 serving threads?

Comment: I had an answer with references to Twisted and Django, but I retracted it after another read of your question, because you might want to do this specific with web.py

Comment: @mvw Yes, it is the limit of 10 serving threads. My calculation is very quick - less than a millisecond, but it is done on the content of a web page. This page has to first be fetched, and this takes a second or two, so the threads are mostly waiting. I'm not using the power of my machine - I need many more serving threads. I'm not locked into _web.py_; I chose it because it looked simple to handle; I would welcome ideas, thanks.